# android AlertDialog with transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency, android-alertdialog

I have a custom AlertDialog and I want to make it's background completely transparent.
Normally to make an activity completely transparent, I do the following

- set background to `#00000000` in the xml layout
- in the manifest set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"` for the activity.
- In onCreate add `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0))`.

  But now that I am dealing with a Dialog, how do I accomplish transparency?

Here is the dialog code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mine1,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.mine1));
    mine1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mine1.setView(dialoglayout);
    mine1.show();
```

And my xml is just a relativeLayout with other child views:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: I have already looked at some similar posts here, but they don't seem to work.

My real reason is that the background that I really want to use, is not rectangular. I get it to work in an activity. But I want to use a dialog instead.

EDIT:

Further playing around, I have this `style.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Which I add as

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomDialog)
```

Comment: attr `dialogBackground` is not recognized by eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Dialog instead of `AlertDialog.Builder` and so use setContentView instead of setView.

Answer (score 8):

```
    <style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:width">300dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

            Dialog connectionDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomAlertDialog);
            connectionDialog.setContentView(set your view here);
            connectionDialog.show();
```

Comment: Yours accomplishes as much as my own `style.xml`. The background is barely transparent; it's very dark; you must look really hard to see that there is some weak transparency going on. I am looking for `#00000000`. Also, for some reason there is a white border around the background.

Comment: width attribute 300dip is not taking effect.

Answer (score 4):

```
connectionDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its related to `android:backgroundDimEnabled` and/or `android:backgroundDimAmount` in your style. Take a look at this answer for more info: [Translucent Activity filling the entire screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481277/translucent-activity-filling-the-entire-screen)

You might want to try setting `android:backgroundDimEnabled`to false.