# Cannot able to set background fully transparent in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, transparency

This is the code I have used. My MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void broadcastIntent(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    alertDialog.show();
  } 
 }
```

My dialog layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#00000000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtJioMoney"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="First"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:id="@+id/txtCashOnPick"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

      </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

My main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Broadcast Intent"
    android:onClick="broadcastIntent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using the AppCompatActivity so I cannot able to use @android:style/Theme.Translucent in my manifest. I want my dialog to be fully transparent I don't need that white background.

[image: sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

There has been many answers to this question, next time try to search on stackoverflow or google before you post your question.

[set Transparent background to alertdialog in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186818/set-transparent-background-to-alertdialog-in-android)

[Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)

[android AlertDialog with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579017/android-alertdialog-with-transparent-background)

Additionally, instead of using the xml style, you could also try to use .setAlpha(0) on your Relative layout programmatically.