# How to show translucent activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparency

How can I create a translucent activity on top of my activity to show help contents? I've seen many apps showing help content over a translucent screen(like when a spinner dropdown is shown, the rest of the screen goes dim and the drop down is projected. I want to create that dim screen)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translucent Activity filling the entire screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481277/translucent-activity-filling-the-entire-screen)

Comment: pls don't close, due to extra value provided in accepted answer - the "flash" is a problem with transparent screens, and this shows how to fix that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare your activity in manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

and add a transparent background to your layout.

To avoid black flickering you should disable activity animation by creating a style:

```
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

then in manifest set it as theme for activity or whole application.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.yourActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
</activity>
```

Or just specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag when starting activity.

Answer (score 6):

Just set the appropriate theme to your activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

You could set the theme in `onCreate()` of your activity, but you will see a black flickering for the time between the setup of the activity.

Comment: Perfect solution to avoid flickering between activity transition........You could set the theme in onCreate() of your activity, but you will see a black flickering for the time between the setup of the activity.